# Can I grab a particular verse from arabluatex?

Tags: arabluatex

In the doc I've seen that using `\quransurah[number]` I can put any surah in my document AND now I'm wondering whether I can grab a particular verse of any surah!

Is there something like `\quransurah[114][3]` to grab the 3rd verse of surah 114?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Surah's are not a part of the `arabluatex` package itself, you need to load the `quran` package to print the Surah's. In the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/quran/doc/quran-doc.pdf) of that package various commands are described, for printing a Surah, an Ayah, a range of Ayat, a specific page of Quran, and some others. Translations of each Surah in German, English and Persian are also available.

MWE for a single Ayah, using the command `\quranayah[Surah nr][Ayah number]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabluatex}
\usepackage{quran}
\begin{document}
\begin{txarab}
\quransurah[107]
\end{txarab}
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}
\hspace*{1cm} single verse:
\begin{txarab}
\quranayah[107][2]
\end{txarab}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Can we link our local translation to this package by some mechanism (ie, using lua, json, xml, etc)?

Comment: @EmonHaque I don't think that would be easy, you could try to post a feature request on https://github.com/javadr/quran to see what the author of the package thinks about it.